# #include in Expect script

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, automation, expect

So I am having trouble making TestCases with expect scripts, I have like 10 TestCases which all starts and ends with the same "functions" like login and logout or turning some flags off, is there a possibility to include them or execute them remotely from my script, like `spawn login.exp` or even better to put them in functions ?

TC01.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 5

#example of getting arguments passed from command line..
#not necessarily the best practice for passwords though...
set server [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set pass [lindex $argv 2]
set no [lindex $argv 3]
set counter 0

# connect to server via ssh, login, and su to root
send_user "connecting to $server\n"
spawn ssh $user@$server

#login handles cases:
#   login with keys (no user/pass)
#   user/pass
#   login with keys (first time verification)
expect {
  "> " { }
  "$ " { }

  "assword: " { 
        send "$pass\n" 
        expect {
          "> " { }
          "$ " { }
          "assword: " { 
                    send_user "\nLogin failed\n" 
                                    incr counter 1
                    exit 5

                }
        }
  }
  "(yes/no)? " { 
        send "yes\n"
        expect {
          "> " { }
          "$ " { }
        }
  }
 default {
        send_user "Login failed\n"
        incr counter 1
        exit
  }
}


#TEST CASE HERE


#login out
send "exit\n"

expect {
    "> " {}
    default {}
}


if { $counter > 0 } {
    send_user "\nTestCase finished with some errors!\nFAILED!!!\nERRORS $counter\n";
    exit 4;
}

send_user "\nTestCase finished with SUCCESS!\nERRORS: $counter\n";
```

So i would like to have login and count_error as functions, so I would be able to create my test cases just like this:

TC01.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 5
set server [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set pass [lindex $argv 2]
set no [lindex $argv 3]
set counter 0


login($server, $user, $pass)

#TestCase

Errors($counter)
exit
```

Comment: yes. show us what you have and we can help you refactor. as you question stands now, that's about as much help as you can get.

Comment: I've updated my quiestion, I hope this time I've explained it better.

Answer (score 2):

Expect is actually Tcl with some bindings to pty's and fork() thrown in. All very well described on http://tcl.tk
Functions in Tcl are done with proc (look [here](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/proc.htm)) eg:

lib.tcl

```
proc login {server user pass} {
  # Your expect code goes here
  return $errorCount
}
proc errors {errorCount} { 
  if {$errorCount > 0} {
    # Your error handling code here
  }
}
```

test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
source lib.tcl
set errors [login $server $user $pass]
# your test case here
errors $errors
```